# Im 20. Jahrhundert verwendete Schreibschriften

Tags: handwriting

Nach meinem Wissen wurden Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts in Deutschland standardmäßig Sütterlin und  die deutsche Kurrentschrift verwendet. Erst 1941 verboten die Nazis die deutsche Kurrentschrift und die lateinische Schreibschrift wurde zur alleinigen „deutschen Normalschrift“ erklärt (vgl. [Schreibschrift](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibschrift#Reformen_und_Abschaffung_der_deutschen_Kurrentschrift) und [Antiqua-Fraktur-Streit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiqua-Fraktur-Streit#Der_%C3%9Cbergang_zum_alleinigen_Gebrauch_der_Antiqua)).

**Anmerkung** aufgrund des Kommentars von Carsten S: Die Frage bezieht sich primär auf Deutschland. Dennoch ist es auch interessant, wie die Situation in anderen Gebieten des deutschen Sprachraums war.

Meine Großmutter (geb. 1902 in München, auch dort zur Schule gegangen) verwendete allerdings niemals die „traditionellen“ deutschen Schriftarten, sondern - soweit ich das beurteilen kann - eine Variante der lateinischen Schreibschrift. Hier Beispiele ihrer Handschrift aus den Jahren 1924 bzw. 1939:

[image]

[image]

Ich vermute, dass sie in der Schule so zu schreiben gelernt hat. Mein Großvater, geb. 1901 in Bayern (Allgäu), hat dagegen bis ins hohe Alter Sütterlin benutzt.

> **Meine Frage daher: Ab wann wurde die lateinischen Schreibschrift in Schulen gelehrt? War das Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts eher eine Ausnahme und gab es regionale Besonderheiten?**

**Ergänzung aufgrund von RHas Kommentar:**

Von Sütterlin wurde 1913 eine lateinische Schriftvariante vorgeschlagen. Ob bzw. wann sich diese an Schulen durchgesetzt hat, ist mir nicht bekannt. Für die Schulzeit meine Großmutter dürfte Sütterlins lateinische Variante ohnehin keine Rolle mehr gespielt haben (zumal sie als Tochter aus einem armen Elternhaus über den Besuch der "Volksschule" nicht hinauskam). Übrigens verwendete ihre jüngere Schwester, die diesselbe Münchner Schule besucht haben dürfte, ebenfalls die o.g. lateinische Schriftvariante. Das deutet darauf hin, dass beide Mädchen ihre Schreibschrift an der Schule gelernt haben und sich nicht autodidaktisch zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt angeeignet haben. Letzteres wäre in ihrem sozialen Milieu auch äußerst unwahrscheinlich gewesen.

Zum Abschluss noch zwei weitere Beispiele der Verwendung lateinischer Handschrift:

[image]

[image]

**2. Ergänzung:**

Die Anordnung der Nazis, die im Jahre 1941 die lateinische Schreibschrift zur alleinigen „deutschen Normalschrift“ erklärte, könnte ein Indiz dafür sein, dass die lateinische Schreibschrift bereits Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts allgemein bekannt war oder von praktisch allen zumindest gelesen werden konnte. Anderenfalls wäre die Anordnung kaum umsetzbar gewesen.

Ein interessanter Artikel zum Thema "Abschaffung der Deutschen Schrift durch de Nazis " findet sich [hier](https://www.beirat-fuer-geschichte.de/fileadmin/pdf/band_12/Demokratische_Geschichte_Band_12_Essay_5.pdf).

Ein weiterer Hinweis zur Bekanntheit von "nichtdeutschen" Schriftarten ergibt sich m.E. aus der Verwendung vion Schreibmaschinen. Zitat aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibmaschinenschrift):

Schreibmaschinen-Fraktur

In der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts gab es im deutschen Sprachraum auch Schreibmaschinen mit Frakturtypen. Diese hatten im Allgemeinen die frakturtypischen Ligaturen ch, ck, tz, st und das lange s als zusätzliche Zeichen. Die Schreibmaschinenfraktur war nicht vereinheitlicht, d. h. es gab mehrere Versionen. Die häufigste war eine Schrift, die von der gewöhnlichen Buchfraktur abgeleitet war. Es gab aber auch Schwabacher- (bzw. die so genannte Neue Schwabacher) und einfache Texturaschriften. Einige dieser Frakturschriften hatten auch leicht unterschiedliche Strichstärken. Eine Besonderheit dieser Schreibmaschinen war zumindest bei einigen, dass auch die Tastenkappen in Frakturschrift beschriftet waren. **Die Frakturschriften setzten sich aber auf der Schreibmaschine nicht durch, da sie als nicht-proportionale Schreibmaschinenschriften sehr schwer zu lesen sind. Versuche, Schreibmaschinen mit proportionalen Frakturschriften auszurüsten, schlugen ebenfalls fehl.**

Comment: Da Dein erster Satz Deutschland erwähnt, könntest hinzufügen, ob sich Deine Frage nur darauf bezieht oder auf welche anderen Gebiete des deutschen Sprachraums auch. Das wird hier teils sehr wichtig genommen ;)

Comment: Ich habe den Link auf die eigentliche Quelle der Information gesetzt und noch einen weiteren ergänzt; falls mir jemand einen schlüssigen Grund dafür nennt, [WikiZero](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WikiZero) gegenüber Wikipedia zu bevorzugen, mache ich die Änderung gerne rückgängig.

Comment: Von der Sütterlin gab es auch eine lateinische Variante. Zur Frage, wo und in welchem Umfang die eingesetzt wurde, konnte ich allerdings nichts finden.

Comment: @RHa Danke für den Hinweis, das war mir nicht bekannt. Das Ganze bleibt trotzdem rätselhaft, Sütterlin hat die lateinische Variante erst 1913 vorgeschlagen - wohl zu spät für mein Großmutter.

Comment: Im deutschan Sprachraum ist es anscheinlich üblich gewesen, dass Gebildete sowohl eine lateinische als auch eine "deutsche" Schreibschrift lernen. Dazu Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateinische_Schreibschrift

Comment: @RHa Das klingt plausibel. Allerdings kam meine Großmutter aus einem bildungsfernen Milieu und hat nur ein Minimum an Schulbildung erhalten. Sie las aber gerne Gedichte und schrieb sie teilweise auf (vgl. obige Bilder). Zahlreiche Gedichte konnte sie außerdem bis ins hohe Alter auswendig rezitieren. Das zeigt eine Affinität zur Poesie, die jedoch eher nicht seitens der Schule gefördert worden sein dürfte. Vielleicht war es so, dass manche Schulen doch schon um 1900 die lateininsche Scheibschrift lehrten. Mich interessiert, was zu diesem Thema bekannt ist.

Comment: @PaulFrost: ich bin hier kleinlich: welches Deutschland? Es gab um 1870 ein  anderes als 1900 als 1919 als 1945 als 1949 als 1990, um mal wesentliche Marker zu nennen. Historiker verwenden entsprechend die amtlichen Staatsbezeichnungen wodurch sich der Zeitraum schon stärker eingrenzt. (und die eigentliche Frage würde ich im Text mehr hervorheben)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Die Frage habe ich nun deutlich hervorgehoben. Auch wenn sich Deutschland als staatlich-geographische Entität im Laufe der Geschiche verändert hat: "Anfang des 20. Jahrhunderts" stellt klar, dass die Spätphase des Deutschen Kaiserreichs (bis 1918) und die Weimarer Republik (1919- 1933) gemeint ist. Wenn es bzgl. der Schriftverwendung einen Bruch **nach** 1918 gegeben haben sollte, wäre diese Information Teil der Antwort. Das Beispiel meiner Großmutter spricht aber gegen diese Annahme.

Comment: @PaulFrost: okay, für mich überraschend, ich wäre aus der Frage heraus auf die Idee gekommen, dass die Zeit 1880-1930 relevant ist. Denn wenn Deine 1902 geborene Großmutter nur lateinisch schrieb, dann ist das schon vor dem 1. WK in die Schulen gekommen. Jedenfalls unterliege ich dem Glauben, dass sie nicht erst nach 1918 = mit 16 Jahren anfing schreiben zu lernen, in den Trümmern des 1. WKs.

Comment: @PaulFrost Zum einen könnte die Dame es im Laufe des Französisch-Unterrichts gelernt haben. Es könnte also unzweckmäßig sein, sich ausschließlich auf Schriftreform im Deutschen zu konzentrieren! Zum anderen kannte ich auch in meiner Familie Frauen, die sich weit von der Eingangsschrift entfernten.

Comment: @Ludi Wie in meiner Frage erwähnt, hat meine Großmutter nur ein Minimum an Schulbildung erhalten (die soziale Herkunft war immer schon ein Bildungshemmnis, und meine Urgroßeltern waren wirklich ganz weit unten in der Pyramide). Fremdsprachen hat sie keine gelernt und autodidaktische Aneignung halte ich für äußerst unwahrscheinlich. Also spricht alles für die Schrifterlernung in ihrer Münchner Volksschule (dürfte in den Jahren ab 1908 gewesen sein).

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Völlig richtig, meine Großmutter muss die Schrift in den ersten Jahren ihres Schulunterrichts erlernt haben (d.h. definitiv vor Beginn des 1. Weltkriegs). Meine Frage bezieht sich aber nicht nur auf ihren speziellen Fall und ich möchte sie nicht auf das Kaiserreich beschränken. Aber selbstverständlich freue mich auch über Antworten, die den Status bis 1918 erläutern.

Comment: @Ludi Interessant ist aber, dass es historisch eine gewisse Affinität zwischen Frankreich und Bayern gegeben hat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Volksschulen waren im Kaiserreich Gemeindeschulen, von einem Lehrplan im heutigen Sinne konnte nicht die Rede sein. Kurrentschrift und lateinische Schreibschrift wurden beide im deutschen Raum benutzt.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateinische_Schreibschrift#Im_deutschen_Sprachraum

Ich vemute, dass es damals Glückssache war, was man in der Schule gelernt hat. Meine schwäbischen Großeltern, die ebenfalls ca. 1910 geboren waren, haben lateinisch geschrieben, wenn auch mit Strich über dem u und anderen Einflüssen der Kurrentschrift, während andere Mitglieder der Familie (wie die Kusine meiner Großmutter) Kurrentschrift geschrieben haben. Die Schulbildung weiß ich nicht genau, aber Abitur hatten die alle nicht.

Comment: So oder so ähnlich würde ich das auch auffassen. Meine Großeltern, auch zu der Zeit geboren, konnten beides (aber keine "Bildungsbürger", vermutlich das Lateinische selbst gelernt). Meine Eltern, in den späten 40ern in die Schule gekommen konnten das noch lesen aber schreiben weiß ich nicht. Meinereiner nicht mehr.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Passt zu meiner 2. Ergänzung!